# Displaying raw HTML on b-table of bootstrap-vue with event click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying get event of v-html in b-table

the "**options**" session was inserted with v-html

[image: b-table of boostrap-vue using v-html]

```
    <b-table striped hover :items="clusters" :fields="fields" :borderless="true" :busy="statusRequest">
      <template v-slot:cell(id)="data">
        <div v-html="table_option_html"></div>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:table-busy>
        <div class="text-center text-secondary my-2">
          <b-spinner class="align-middle"></b-spinner>
          <strong> Loading...</strong>
        </div>
      </template>
    </b-table>
```

in the code above i'm inserting the html here

```
<template v-slot:cell(id)="data">
        <div v-html="table_option_html"></div>
      </template>
```

this is value of **table_option_html**

```
table_option_html: `
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" title="Excluir" @click="action("aaa")"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" title="Testar"><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" title="Editar"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
    `
```

**@click** event does not work to call action

```
methods: {
    action: function(event) {
      console.log(event);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v-html` does not work for rendering components or vue special attributes (like `@event` handlers, `v-model`, etc.).

Your best bet is to render the buttons in the slot and attach the @click events to the button (this way Vue is in control of the DOM handlers), rather than via `v-html`.

The other option is event delegation on the `<div>` (i.e. `<div @click="handler($evtent)">`, and inspect the `event.target` to see if it was a click on a button (or inside a button) and which button was clicked.

```js
handler(evt) {
  if(evt.target) {
    const button = evt.target.closest('button')
    if (button) {
      const title = button.getAttrubute('title')
      // do something based on what title the button has
    }
  }
}
```